How to find the limit of this expression as $x\to0$?
How can we find the limit of the expression $y$ as $x$ approaches $0$?
$$y=\left(\dfrac{e}{\left(1+x\right)^\tfrac1x}\right)^\tfrac1x$$
I solved this after looking up the expansion of $(1+x)^\frac1x$, but I was wondering if the limit can be evaluated without the expansion.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Take natural logarithms on both sides and then use L'Hôpital's rule. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule

After having taken natural logarithms on both sides and used L'Hôpital's rule, then use $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} e^{f(x)} = \exp (\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x))$.

Using the series expansion gives more than the limit. You also have a nice approximation of the corresponding function close to $x=0$

It surely can, although the series expansion is certainly the most elegant way.
We begin by taking the log of the expression, then we evaluate the limit and apply the exponential function. Being $\log x$ continuous over $\mathbb R_+$, it is sufficient to prove that the limit you're looking for exists and is positive to apply this reasoning, and it's a nice exercise to prove that $y>0$ over $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$.
So, coming to the limit itself, we have
$$\log y = \frac1x\log\left(\frac e{(1+x)^{\frac1x}}\right) \tag 1$$
You can now apply L'Hôpital's rule, which gives
$$L = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)-\frac x{x+1}}{x^2} \tag 2$$
Which is equal to the limit of $(1)$ as $x$ approaches $0$. Apply L'Hôpital's rule again, so that you get
$$L = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{{x}/{(1+x)^2}}{2x} \tag 3$$
Which is trivial. Your limit will be $e^L$.
